# Error "Could not find or load main class" when using gradle to build the project in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle

The project has the following file structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qr5F.png)

build.gradle:

```
...
jar {
    baseName = 'billiard-viewer'
    manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': 'billiards.viewer.Main'
    //manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': 'fake_main'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
    }
}
...
```

And the artifact was set up as:
[Artifacts Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOojx.png)

When I build and run the program in Intellij, it works perfectly. However, when I try to build it into a standalone JAR program, it keeps giving me `Error: Could not find or load main class fake_main`.

Could anyone give me some ideas about what could be the reason behind this and how I can solve it?

Comment: How do you build it as a JAR?

Comment: Don’t do that. Use the application plugin.

Comment: I use the Build->Build Artificts option in Intellij. I am pretty sure that the artifacts setting is fine, since it was quite straight forward

Comment: I think somebody had a similar question before Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: I don't think they are the same problem. If you look at the file structure, you will see that the main is there, under billiards/viewer. And it can run from debug mode. It doesn't work only when I try to pack it into a JAR.